# Unable To Save CustomMetadata in Firebase Cloud Storage With Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, metadata, firebase-storage

## Result

In the following code an *mp3* file is successfully uploaded to a Firebase **Bucket** in a *Cloud Function* using *Node.js* according to the 
[*Extend Cloud Storage with Cloud Functions*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#download_transform_and_upload_a_file) documentation, similar to the [example image transformation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation). When the *mp3* file is selected in the Firebase console or streamed on Android via *ExoPlayer* it plays as expected. However,  the Metadata is not shown as uploaded in Firebase's console.

## Expected

The `CustomMetadata` object to be uploaded with the *mp3* file per the [Custom Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#custom_metadata) documentation. The use case is uploading an `APIC` `ID3`metadata tag with an *mp3*'s image URL in order to consume by *ExoPlayer* on Android.

**Firebase Console**

[image]

## Setup

*Note: This is a portion of the full code for brevity.*

The metadata `location` and `activity`  are from the documentation example in order to test whether uploading custom metadata works.

```
...
.then(() => {
    if (exists === false) {
      return bucket.upload(tempAudioFile, { 
        destination: audioFilePath,  
        metadata: {
          contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
          customMetadata: {
            'location': 'Yosemite, CA, USA',
            'activity': 'Hiking'
          }
        }
      })
    } else {
      throw new Error("Audiocast exists.") 
    }
  })
...
```

Answer (score 15):

The [Cloud function syntax](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File) for custom metadata differs from the frontend library. Instead of `customMetadata`, use the key `metadata`. In your case:

```
metadata: {
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    metadata: {
        'location': 'Yosemite, CA, USA',
        'activity': 'Hiking'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ben, this is a good answer. Can you add a link for future readers to reference?

Comment: Thanks John for the suggestion.

Comment: I wonder why they would do such a thing which is almost sure to waste pretty much everyone a good amount of time. People would assume things should be more consistent across different APIs.